# Convert strings to UPPERCASE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, uppercase

What is the T-SQL function for converting strings into upper case in SQL Server?

Answer (score 56):

[UPPER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055.aspx)

```
SELECT UPPER(LastName) + ', ' + FirstName AS Name
FROM Person.Person
```

Answer (score 16):

Try `UPPER` function:

```
SELECT UPPER('Hello world!!!')
```

Result:

```
HELLO WORLD!!!
```